# How do I use the DOM Explorer in Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Has anyone been able to use the DOM Explorer to debug their Win 8 apps?

I do not see a DOM Explorer tab when debugging as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh696632.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the Debug > Windows > DOM Explorer menu command to show the DOM Explorer tab.

[image: Showing the DOM Explorer]

Comment: Thanks, be nice if Microsoft included this in _their_ tutorial.

Comment: The "Debugger Type" for the project must also be set to "Script Only"