# Where's the DOM Explorer in Visual Studio Express 2012 Express for Web?

Tags: html, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I saw the answer for windows 8 here: [How do I use the DOM Explorer in Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692357/how-do-i-use-the-dom-explorer-in-visual-studio-express-2012-rc-for-windows-8)

But this is what I see:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the DOM Explorer & JavaScript Console are only available in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8, not in the ones for Web or desktop. Don't know about the full blown versions.

- T C Ahonen

Comment: I think so too, as I have both versions of VS Express 2012.